# Function has no reference to my predefined variable

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm very new to JavaScript so I might did not get the basics right.
I'm trying to open a new page based on the currents page URL. But it seems that the function has no reference to the current URL.

It should be a simple Firefox Addon that looks at the URL, replaces a certain part and opens the "new" page in a new tap.

```
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
  var path = window.location.href
  var newPath = path.replace('www', 'test')
  var creating = browser.tabs.create({
    "url": "${newPath}"
  });
});
```

Being on `www.google.com` it should open me a new tap with `test.google.com`. Instead it opens me a Tab with the following URL=`moz-extension://fde3def8-cf60-4536-b96b-1bf7ed91a8da/$%7BnewPath%7D`.
Taking a look at the end of the URL I think it has no reference to the variable. When replacing the `newPath` variable in the last line with a static sample URL e.g. `www.facebook.com` it works fine.

Comment: [Background script](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension#Background_scripts) (where your `browserAction` code is) runs in the context of a _**special page**_ (background page) which has no relation to regular web pages. That's why `window.location.href` has that weird (for you) value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extension pages, such as an extension pop-up page, are separate pages. They run in a separate context that has no (or very little) connection to the regular currently open page.

Your `path` is the URL of the extension, which apparently happens to be "`moz-extension://fde3def8-cf60-4536-b96b-1bf7ed91a8da/`". You are trying to replace parts of that URL and open the result in a new tab.

#### Read up on architecture of extensions first:

- [Anatomy of an extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Anatomy_of_a_WebExtension)
- [Achitecture of extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) (for Chrome, but the concept is the
  same)

To accomplish what you are trying to do, you will probably have to first query the active tab using [`tabs.query({active: true})`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/query) to get its URL.

#### Note on asynchronous execution:

Many extension related APIs (including `tabs.query`) are asynchronous (promise-based in Firefox). [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises) might be a bit difficult to grasp for beginers.

#### You also confuse strings and template strings:

This is also incorrect: `"url": "${newPath}"`. It should be simply `"url": newPath`. You seem to be confusing regular strings with [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 0):

String interpolation in JS works only with backticks not with quotation marks as in: `` "url": `${newPath}` ``